# JSON - out of memory error

Tags: json, postgresql, out-of-memory, postgresql-9.6

```
CREATE TABLE X AS
SELECT json_array_elements(json_rmq -> 'orders'::text) AS order
FROM table_name
WHERE blah;
```

I get out of memory error.

Is there anything I can do to unpack the above?

The JSON column is about ~5 MB and it has about 150,000 array elements in 'orders' above.
I tried `work_mem` values up to 250MB and it did not help, the query takes about same time to fail. I guess this parameter does not help JSON processing.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this on PostgreSQL mailing list and received answer. 
It is a memory leak/bug in JSON part of PostgreSQL, it is fixed in version 10.0. For a possible work around see the PostgreSQL mailing list archives (dates of ~3-5 for Dec 2017).

Comment: A legimate bug in Postgresql, https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/15699.1512347969%40sss.pgh.pa.us